# Why isn't this HTML5 Geocoding function in JS working?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, navigator

I'm very new to javascript (read: today). I have the following to use HTML5 geocoding:

```
function geocode() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var pos = geocodeWithHTML5();
        alert('geocode - Lat: ' + pos.lat + ', Lng: ' + pos.lng);
    }
}

function geocodeWithHTML5() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latlng = {
            lat: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
            lng: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)
        };
        alert('navigator - Lat: ' + latlng.lat + ', Lng: ' + latlng.lng);
        return latlng;
    }, function() {
        return false;
    });
}
```

Alert `navigator` works as expected.

Alert `geocode` causes an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`.

I thought adding `return` in front of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` might work, but it made no difference.

I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong here...

**UPDATE:** Changed to this, but now I get two alerts. The first has `undefined` values, the second has the correct values:

```
function geocode() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // If browser supports HTML5 GeoLocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        geocodeWithHTML5(function(pos){
            alert('navigator - Lat: ' + pos.lat + ', Lng: ' + pos.lng);
        });
    } else {
        // Alternative GeoLocation
    }
}

function geocodeWithHTML5(fn) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
            lng: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)
        };
        fn(pos);
    }, fn(false));
}
```

Comment: Sorry @deceze, I still don't really understand. Is navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition asynchronous? I thought it just pulls data that's already there.

Comment: Yes, it's asynchronous. You're passing a callback function to it, which is a sure sign. You can't return something from such a callback function to the "surrounding" code.

Comment: Updated the question - I think I've done something else wrong...

Comment: `fn(false)` is always being called. You want `fn.bind(null, false)`, or `function () { fn(false); }`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I think I mostly understand now.